# Memory leak issue with Python 3.5.3 under Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x

When running a graphic application with Python 3.5.3 under Linux on a raspberry pi 3 board the application memory usage grows steadily and the board eventually crushes after a time period of approximately five minutes.

I have recently modified a Python script that previously only worked with Python 2.7.13
but didn’t work with Python 3 (Python version: 3.5.3). Backward compatibility with Python 2 is not required. 
As part of this process I had to install two new libraries that specifically used by 
Python 3 (python3-pyside and python3-pyqtgraph). Now the application seems to be working 
with Python 3.5.3 but I’m seeing memory leak (this is running on a Raspberry pi 3 board under Linux, Python version is 3.5.3). 
It takes about five minutes for the board to crash completely.

I was able to narrow down the problem to a single line of code, please see below:

```
imageType_DisplayImageFinal = QtGui.QImage(imageType_DisplayImage, 
imageType_DisplayImage.shape[1], imageType_DisplayImage.shape[0], 
imageType_DisplayImage.strides[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
```

The code works fine in Python 2.7.13 so I have a feeling that the problem is not with the Python code itself but with the newly installed libraries (python3-pyside and python3-pyqtgraph) but not 100% sure.

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening and how to fix it? Perhaps a different "pyside" version should be installed. Will "PySide2" make a difference?
Thank you in advance for your help and time and please let me know if you need additional information.

It seems that the problem is resulted by the following line of code:

```
imageType_DisplayImageFinal = QtGui.QImage(imageType_DisplayImage, 
imageType_DisplayImage.shape[1], imageType_DisplayImage.shape[0], 
imageType_DisplayImage.strides[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
```

As mentioned earlier the application seems to be working fine with Python 3.5.3 but only for a limited time due to memory leak. As time goes on the application’s memory usage grows steadily and the board crushes after about 5 minutes. How can I prevent the memory leak from happening?

Based on my observation the memory leak issue is resulted by the use of function QtGui.QImage() that is called from function display_video_stream().

Here is minimal source code:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore, QtUiTools
from pyqtgraph import GraphicsLayoutWidget
import sys
import cv2

H_RES                  = 640
V_RES                  = 480
IDLE_SAMPLE_DELAY      = 100

class MainWindow (QtGui.QMainWindow):
    data_signal = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        file = QtCore.QFile("./main_gui.ui")
        file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
        self.myWidget = loader.load(file, self)
        file.close()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.myWidget)
        self.setWindowTitle("MINIMAL CODE")
        self.graphicsView = GraphicsLayoutWidget(self.myWidget)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.myWidget.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.graphicsView)   
        self.refreshCameraList()
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.display_video_stream)
        self.openCamera()

    def openCamera(self):
        if self.capture.isOpened():
            self.capture.release()
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,H_RES)
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,V_RES)
        self.timer.start(IDLE_SAMPLE_DELAY)

    def refreshCameraList(self):
        numberOfDevices = 0;
        noError = 1;
        while (noError == 1):
            try:
                self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(numberOfDevices)
                if self.capture.isOpened():
                    numberOfDevices = numberOfDevices + 1
                    self.capture.release()
                else:
                    noError = 0
            except:
                noError = 0

    def display_video_stream(self):
        _, imageType_DisplayImage = self.capture.read()        
        imageType_DisplayImageFinal = QtGui.QImage(imageType_DisplayImage, imageType_DisplayImage.shape[1], imageType_DisplayImage.shape[0], imageType_DisplayImage.strides[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.myWidget.lblVideoStream.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(imageType_DisplayImageFinal))

def main():
    global serial
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And below is the content of the XML file main_gui.ui that is loaded in the above snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MyWidget</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="MyWidget">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1920</width>
    <height>1080</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>1920</width>
    <height>1080</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
   <enum>Qt::NoContextMenu</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MinimalCode</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
   <item>
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="_2">
     <item>
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout" columnstretch="0,2,1">
       <item row="1" column="1">
        <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3"/>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="2">
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
         <item>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
           <item>
            <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
             <property name="orientation">
              <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
             </property>
             <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
              <size>
               <width>40</width>
               <height>20</height>
              </size>
             </property>
            </spacer>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_19">
             <property name="sizePolicy">
              <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
               <horstretch>0</horstretch>
               <verstretch>0</verstretch>
              </sizepolicy>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string>Current Level</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QLCDNumber" name="lcdCurrent">
             <property name="sizePolicy">
              <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="Minimum">
               <horstretch>0</horstretch>
               <verstretch>0</verstretch>
              </sizepolicy>
             </property>
             <property name="minimumSize">
              <size>
               <width>200</width>
               <height>100</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="smallDecimalPoint">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="digitCount">
              <number>4</number>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </item>
         <item>
          <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_5">
           <property name="sizeConstraint">
            <enum>QLayout::SetFixedSize</enum>
           </property>
           <item row="0" column="1">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="lblDifferenceRed">
             <property name="text">
              <string/>
             </property>
             <property name="digitCount">
              <number>4</number>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="2" column="0">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_22">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Difference (B)</string>
             </property>
             <property name="alignment">
              <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="3" column="0">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_24">
             <property name="text">
              <string>PWM Top:</string>
             </property>
             <property name="alignment">
              <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="4" column="0">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_25">
             <property name="text">
              <string>PWM Bottom:</string>
             </property>
             <property name="alignment">
              <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="1" column="0">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_23">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Difference (G)</string>
             </property>
             <property name="alignment">
              <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="0" column="0">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_21">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Difference (R)</string>
             </property>
             <property name="alignment">
              <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="1" column="1">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="lblDifferenceGreen">
             <property name="text">
              <string/>
             </property>
             <property name="digitCount">
              <number>4</number>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="2" column="1">
            <widget class="QLabel" name="lblDifferenceBlue">
             <property name="text">
              <string/>
             </property>
             <property name="digitCount">
              <number>4</number>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="4" column="1">
            <widget class="QLineEdit" name="PWMbottom">
             <property name="text">
              <string>0</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="3" column="1">
            <widget class="QLineEdit" name="PWMtop">
             <property name="text">
              <string>1</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item row="3" column="2">
            <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
             <property name="orientation">
              <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
             </property>
             <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
              <size>
               <width>40</width>
               <height>20</height>
              </size>
             </property>
            </spacer>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </item>
         <item>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
           <item>
            <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
             <item>
              <widget class="QLabel" name="label_20">
               <property name="text">
                <string>Desired Level</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item>
              <widget class="QLCDNumber" name="lcdDesired">
               <property name="sizePolicy">
                <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="Minimum">
                 <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                 <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                </sizepolicy>
               </property>
               <property name="minimumSize">
                <size>
                 <width>200</width>
                 <height>100</height>
                </size>
               </property>
               <property name="digitCount">
                <number>4</number>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="1">
        <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="Minimum">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>0</width>
           <height>0</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="currentIndex">
          <number>2</number>
         </property>
         <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Maximum">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <attribute name="title">
           <string>Camera Feed</string>
          </attribute>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
           <item>
            <widget class="QLabel" name="lblVideoStream">
             <property name="text">
              <string/>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </widget>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="2">
        <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_4">
         <item row="9" column="2">
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnStartLog">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Start Logging</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```